# Use of lounge overnight at NRT

Tags: nrt, lounges

In a few months will be traveling from Calgary to Mumbai via Narita. I have a 21 hour, overnight connection at NRT. If I use the KAL lounge airside, which publishes itself to be open during the day only, can I remain there during the night?

Comment: "during the day only" what about that is unclear?

Comment: I was unclear if the open hours only referred to when you can enter and register yourself or they actually ask all pax to leave at closing time

Answer (score 2):

The KAL Business Lounge [closes at 8:50pm](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/lounge/tokyo-narita-airport/kal-business-lounge-nrt.htm). While I've occasionally known an airport lounge to extend its hours due to flight delays, I've never seen one that allows people to remain once it does, in fact, close. So no, you will not be allowed to stay in the closed lounge overnight.

[Sleeping in Airports](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/guides/tokyo-narita-airport-guide.htm) has information about staying overnight at Narita, though for 21 hours, you have plenty of time to leave the airport, get a place to sleep, and see a little bit of the city.

Comment: Thanks. That was useful.
To leave the airside, I would need a transit visa. I am leaving my country about 4 months before my return. The transit visa, if I seek to get one, is valid for only 3 months. I'll have to see if they will issue me a transit visa while I am in Canada.

Comment: @Emilio You might be able to get a ["shore pass"](https://www.google.com/search?q=japan+shore+pass) in such situations to leave the airside, though that's apparently at the discretion of the immigration officers, doesn't seem to have well defined rules, and I'm not entirely sure how it works.

Comment: I am not sure if I'm eligible for a shore pass. From other answers I have seen, it looks like a shore pass is issued in unforeseeable circumstances like missing a connection or something. correct me if I am wrong. In my case, it is certain that I have a overnight transit. Will they issue a shore pass under such circumstances?

Comment: @Emilio I'm honestly not sure, and don't have good information on that. Maybe ask a new question about your specific circumstances? It's possible someone else will have the necessary knowledge.